Is there a C# source generator which updates/adds arguments to a function?
I have a function defined as follow public void FunctionA(params object args[])
and I can call it like this FunctionA(1+2, a+b);
Is there a way for source generator to change the call to FunctionA(1+2, a+b, "1+2", "a+b"); ?
Basically, I need to have the input args also as a string before evaluation (similar to CallerArgumentExpression attribute functionality).
Can a source generator change/update existing code or just add a new code?

No, source generators cannot modify existing code, only add code

You can get close with CallerArgumentExpression: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQAYACfARgDoAlAVwDsAXASwFsYKBhCFgByYBsYUAMpCAbkzAwAzgG4AsACglTRsQCGxALzEyCxfgCszCHQCCACgDam7LrQbidgEwBdAJT6l+FKWNNTSwhgACsYMAYrVw0oAHNpBysOdX5BKDM4mjZGAFEEHlhpaQC6CwAidTjpMvdo8kIAfmI2IvVYmG1iOhpU9yUAbyUAXyUgA==

What are you really trying to do? The posted code looks rather odd to me, so some context might be useful to avoid X/Y problems.

@canton7 I thought so. But how Fody.PropertyChanged updates the set method?

@JonasH I want to know the passed arguments as a string. Similar to what CallerArgumentExpression is doing, but at the same time using params object[]
For logging and diagnostics purposes.

@Igor Fody isn't a source generator. It's a tool which goes in once your code has been compiled to IL, and modifies the IL directly

You cannot do this with source generators. They cannot modify existing code, only add new code.
Strictly speaking this is possible, in a rather ugly way which is currently in preview (and might yet change / be removed), see Marc's answer or here.
You can get close to what you want with [CallerArgumentExpression]: this lets you specify an extra parameter which is filled in by the compiler at compile-time:
This means you could write:
void FunctionA(object arg, [CallerArgumentExpression("arg")] string? message = null)
{
}

FunctionA(a + 1);

And the compiler would insert a string for message at compile-time:
FunctionA(a + 1, "a + 1");

However, this doesn't seem to play well with params: a params parameter needs to be the last parameter passed to a function, which means you'd need to do this:
void FunctionA([CallerArgumentExpression("args")] string? message = null, params object[] args)
{
}

... but then you'd have to use named parameters to avoid passing a value for message, and you can't use named parameters with params (sensibly), so that doesn't work.
You could remove params, and do:
void FunctionA(object[] args, [CallerArgumentExpression("args")] string? message = null)
{
}

FunctionA([a + 1, a + 2]);

... but then you only have a single message for the whole of args. The compiler inserts the following at compile time:
FunctionA([a + 1, a + 2], "[a + 1, a + 2]");

... which probably isn't what you want.
If you don't mind having multiple overloads for different numbers of parameters, you can do e.g.:
void FunctionA(
    object arg1,
    object arg2,
    [CallerArgumentExpression("arg1")] string? message1 = null,
    [CallerArgumentExpression("arg2")] string? message2 = null)
{
}


"You cannot do this with source generators" - yes you can ;p https://stackoverflow.com/a/78970035/23354

@MarcGravell Strictly true! However, the notes were quite clear that that mechanism wasn't meant for mere mortals like us

I will acknowledge that it is kinda-sorta-preview, but: I feel zero angst using it... of course, my team was one of the target 1st-party consumers, so I might be biased ;p

@MarcGravell By "us" I mean me and Igor, not people like you with certain... special... needs! You've got my upvote of course, and I'll edit mine to be slightly more nuanced

In addition to the CallerArgumentExpression mechanism that @canton7 notes, there is a way to do this with generators... but it is quite a significant amount of work, so it depends whether it is worth it!
But: "interceptors" - you emit a per-call-site interceptor that does what you want
Also needs (in the csproj):
<InterceptorsPreviewNamespaces>$(InterceptorPreviewNamespaces);MyEvilNamespace</InterceptorsPreviewNamespaces>

Output:
3
6
1 + 2
a + b

Code:
using System;
new Foo().Go();
class Foo
{
    public void Go()
    {
        int a = 2, b = 4;
        FunctionA(1 + 2, a + b);
    }
    public void FunctionA(params object[] args) {
        foreach(var arg in args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arg);
        }
    }
}

// YOUR GENERATED CODE, usually in a separate generated file
namespace MyEvilNamespace
{
    file static class MyInterceptors
    {
        // YOU GENERATE ONE OF THESE FOR EVERY CALL, using the appropriate constant values
        [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InterceptsLocationAttribute("Program.cs", 8, 9)]
        internal static void Intercepted(this Foo @this, object[] args)
        {
            // your code would need to figure out these values, presumably by
            // emitting the Roslyn fragments directly
            @this.FunctionA(args[0], args[1], "1 + 2", "a + b");
        }
    }
}
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    // this type is needed by the compiler to implement interceptors - it doesn't need to
    // come from the runtime itself, though

    [global::System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")] // not needed post-build, so: evaporate
    [global::System.AttributeUsage(global::System.AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
    sealed file class InterceptsLocationAttribute : global::System.Attribute
    {
        public InterceptsLocationAttribute(string path, int lineNumber, int columnNumber)
        {
            _ = path;
            _ = lineNumber;
            _ = columnNumber;
        }
    }
}

